Is there a way of getting accurate elevation data from self-hosted OpenRouteService?
I need to run a customized instance of OpenRouteService with Docker. I have built it from source and it is up and running with an OSM map for Austria - I need ORS to route hiking trails. This is working, but the elevation data is very inaccurate (especially, I need the ascent and descent values to be as precise as possible per route) - on the official hosted API, the values are very accurate. What elevation settings must I use to get the same correct elevation data on my self hosted instance as with the hosted API? It would be fantastic if anybody here has encountered the same issue.
When I make a request for a hiking route to be calculated on the official public ORS API with "elevation" set to true, I get very accurate values for ascent and descent of the route. On the self-hosted API, the data is very inaccurate. I need to self-host ORS because I have custom requirements that necessitate modifying the code and building the API from source.

I do not think this question is about programming, so I think it is off-topic. OSM community may be able to answer, or maybe your sister site about open data or gis (links on top right icons). Probably you should check local country data, which may be more accurate. (Such data is a lucrative business, so there is not much open data. OSM (I think) uses old space shuttle data, but it has some problems on many peaks (if there were ice, you may see them as caldera/volcano).
